# Comonotonic and Countermonotonic RV's and their relation to Frechet Hoeffding Bounds

Tags: independence, copula

If $F_1 ... F_d$ are are all continuous, and $X_j \sim F_j$, $j= 1...d$, then the Frechet upper bound corresponds to comonotonic random variables with 
$$ X_j = F^{-1}_j(F_1(X_1)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [1] $$

In literature, I have seen that comonotonicity corresponds to the Frechet Hoeffding upper bound, but I do not understand why.  The upper bound can be written as:
$$ F^+(\mathbf{x}) = min(F_1(x_1) ... F_d(x_d)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [2] $$

I am not looking for a rigorous proof, although that might also be helpful, but can someone explain why Equation 1 above corresponds to Equation 2?  An intuitive explanation might be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation essentially means that the rank correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$ is one for $i \neq j$.  Put another way, whenever you sample from this joint distribution the individual elements of $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_d)$ will almost surely correspond to the *same quantiles* from their marginal distributions.

Now let's think about the joint distribution function: $F(x) = P(X_1 \leq x_1 \cap X_2 \leq x_2 \cap \ldots \cap X_d \leq x_d)$, and take $i^\prime$ to be the index for which $F_{i^\prime}(x_{i^\prime})$ is the smallest.  This means that $x_{i^\prime}$ is the smallest quantile out of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d$ with regard to the marginal distributions $F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_d$.  Because of comonotonicity the event $\{ X_{i^\prime} \leq x_{i^\prime} \}$ *almost surely coincides* with the event $\{ X_1 \leq x_1 \cap X_2 \leq x_2 \cap \ldots \cap X_d \leq x_d \}$ because if $X_{i^\prime} \leq x_{i^\prime}$, then every other event in this set also occurs with probability one, and the latter event of course implies the former.  This means the two events have the same probability, and so you get equation two.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer! I am still trying to fully understand, can you please explain why equation 1 means that the rank correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$ is 1 for $i \neq j$ ?  Your second sentence, is it correct to say that mathematically:  denote $\mathbf{X_M} = (X_{1M}, X_{2M}, ..., X_{dM})$ as a random vector sampled from the joint distribution.  Then what you are saying is: $F^{-1}_1(X_{1M}) = F^{-1}_1(X_1)$ for $i=1..d$, where $F^{-1}_1(X_1)$ would just be the quantile from the marginal distribution ?

Comment: The function $F_j^{-1}[F_1(x)]$ is monotone increasing, so whenever $X_1$ increases, $X_j$ also increases for $j \neq 1$. (This is the same as saying they have perfect rank correlation.)  You don't want to say $F^{-1}(X_1)$ because $F^{-1}$ is a *quantile function* and has domain $(0, 1)$.  In the equation above we first plug $X_1$ into its own distribution function $F_1(X_1)$, and then plug this into the quantile function $F^{-1}_j$ to obtain a realization from distribution $F_j$.

Comment: To understand equation one it's also important to recognize that $F_1(X_1) \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$, and when $U \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$, $F^{-1}_j(U)$ is a realization of a random variable with distribution $F_j$.  So essentially the relationships stipulated by equation one ensure that the random variables $X_1, \ldots , X_d$ are monotone functions of one another and that they each have their prespecified marginal distributions.

Comment: Also, when I say above that certain things are only true "almost surely," it's because the relationship in equation one only needs to hold with probability one for the random variables to be comonotonic.

Comment: Your explanation make perfect sense as to why Eq [1] ends up generating a random vector with rank correlation is 1, essentially because when $X_1$ is increasing, the way the vector is constructed guarantees that $X_i$ is also increasing, for $i=2..d$.

Comment: You mention that this is another way of saying that if you sample from the individual elements of $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_d)$, these samples correspond to the same quantiles from the joint distribution.  Revising what I wrote earlier, mathematically this means: $X_i = F^{-1}_i(U)$, $U$ because as you pointed out, $F_i(X_i) \sim U(0,1)$, which is in essence a rewrite of Eq [1], right?  Again, as you pointed out, it was incorrect of me to write $F^{-1}_i(X_i)$.